# How to pass dictionary as an argument in some method that will take all the users dynamically from the method and do the desired operations?

Tags: python, robotframework

I struck in one problem in which i have to pass dictionary(or some other data storage data type) as an argument in some method that will take all the users dynamically from the method and do the desired operations . My questions are :

1) Is it possible in robot framework ?

2) If possible then how we are going to do that ?

```
Adding Participant
...  Number_of_users= depend on participants name
...  Participant name= x, y, z, etc..


Adding Participant 
  [Arguments]  ${Number_of_users}  ${Participant name}
  :FOR    ${ELEMENT}    IN   ${Participant name} -->  [How this participant name will be stored dynamically ?]
  \    Log    ${ELEMENT}
  \    Run Keyword  ${ELEMENT} {‌{‌{‌{It will do some operations for user x then in next loop y and so on}}}
```

Comment: Is your question in summary - "how to pass a dictionary  as keyword argument, and loop over its keys?", cause frankly it is unclear to me what you're asking.

Comment: @TodorMinakov  I had given the scenario here --> PF the comments that i mentioned in the code. You will understand, if not Please tell in the code what you are not clear.We will discuss

Comment: You have two blocks of code seemingly named `Adding Participant`. Why two keywords or why two testcases with the same name? Your pseudocode is way too "pseudo", making it hard to understand exactly what you're asking. Are you asking about passing a dictionary, or asking how to loop over a dictionary?

Comment: @TodorMinakov - Yes this is my question what you mentioned-->how to pass a dictionary as keyword argument, and loop over its keys in the particular scenario what i had given

Comment: @BryanOakley  Adding participant in 1st block is the keyword i am using in other script.Adding Participant in 2nd block is the operation that particular keyword is doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to pass a dictionary as a keyword argument? - the same way as any other data type. In the sample below, you can see that, and two easy ways for iterating (looping) over a dictionary's keys:

```
*** Test Cases ***
A case
    ${a dict}=    Create Dictionary     key1=value1    key2=another value
    My Keyword That Works With Dictionaries    ${a dict}

*** Keywords ***
My Keyword That Works With Dictionaries
[Arguments]     ${dct}

    ${the type}=    Evaluate    type($dct)
    Log To Console  The passed argument is of type ${the type}    # will print dict

    ${all keys in the dict}=    Get Dictionary Keys    ${dct}   # a list will all dictionary keys

    # 1st way to iterate/loop
    :FOR   ${key}    IN    @{all keys in the dict}
    \    Log To Console   Working with key ${key}
    \    ${value}=     Get From Dictionary   ${dct}    ${key}
    \    Log To Console   Its value is "${value}" (another way to get it is ${dct['${key}']})

    # the 2nd way
    :FOR   ${key}    IN    @{dct}  
    # this comes from the python's syntax "for key in dct:" - an 
    # iterator over a dictionary returns its keys
    \    Log To Console   Working with key ${key}
    # and so on
```

Answer (score 3):

To pass a dictionary to a keyword, you do it like any other argument. In your case, if you have a dictionary named `${Participants}`, you would pass it as `${Participants}`.

As for iterating over the dictionary, you need to replace `$` with `@`, and use FOR/IN. In this case, the loop variable will have the key, which you can use to retrieve the value.

Example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${Participants}  Create Dictionary  user1="John"  user2="Jane"
    Add Participant  2  ${Participants}


*** Keywords ***
Add Participant
    [Arguments]  ${Number_of_users}  ${Participants}
    :FOR  ${ELEMENT}  IN  @{Participants}
    \  log  element: ${Participants}[${ELEMENT}]
```

The above results in the following log:

[image: screenshot of log file]

Comment: Nitpicking - the log's screenshot doesn't match the code listing - you're logging the value (`${Participants}[${ELEMENT}]`) in it, while the sample code goes for the key (`@{a_dictionary}` returns the keys).

Comment: @TodorMinakov: thanks. I thought I updated it earlier, but clearly didn't. I've updated  the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BryanOakley

Comment: Thanks a lot @TodorMinakov